# How do I abstract over effects and use ContextShift with Scala Cats?

Tags: scala, generics, concurrency, scala-cats

I am creating in Scala and Cats a function that does some I/O and that will be called by other parts of the code. I'm also learning Cats and I want my function to:

- Be generic in its effect and use a `F[_]`
- Run on a dedicated thread pool
- I want to introduce async boundaries

I assume that all my functions are generic in F[_] up to the main method because I'm trying to follow [these Cat's guidelines](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/ioapp.html#why-is-it-specialized-for-io)

But I struggle to make these constraint to work by using `ContextShift` or `ExecutionContext`. I have written a [full example here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ColOfAbRiX/apHC4VJBT9mTxf85O36Mlw/5) and this is an exctract from the example:

```
object ComplexOperation {
  // Thread pool for ComplexOperation internal use only
  val cs = IO.contextShift(
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
  )

  // Complex operation that takes resources and time
  def run[F[_]: Sync](input: String): F[String] =
    for {
      r1 <- Sync[F].delay(cs.shift) *> op1(input)
      r2 <- Sync[F].delay(cs.shift) *> op2(r1)
      r3 <- Sync[F].delay(cs.shift) *> op3(r2)
    } yield r3

  def op1[F[_]: Sync](input: String): F[Int]     = Sync[F].delay(input.length)
  def op2[F[_]: Sync](input: Int): F[Boolean]    = Sync[F].delay(input % 2 == 0)
  def op3[F[_]: Sync](input: Boolean): F[String] = Sync[F].delay(s"Complex result: $input")
}
```

This clearly doesn't abstract over effects as `ComplexOperation.run` needs a `ContextShift[IO]` to be able to introduce async boundaries. What is the right (or best) way of doing this?

Creating `ContextShift[IO]` inside `ComplexOperation.run` makes the function depend on `IO` which I don't want.
Moving the creation of a `ContextShift[IO]` on the caller will simply shift the problem: the caller is also generic in `F[_]` so how does it obtain a `ContextShift[IO]` to pass to `ComplexOperation.run` without explicitly depending on `IO`?

Remember that I don't want to use one global `ContextShift[IO]` defined at the topmost level but I want each component to decide for itself.

Should my `ComplexOperation.run` create the `ContextShift[IO]` or is it the responsibility of the caller?

Am I doing this right at least? Or am I going against standard practices?

Comment: First, you ask for a context shift for your effect, like this: `def sampleFunction[F[_]: Sync`: ContextShif]` and you can use it, the same way you use Sync. Also, if the work is blocking, consider also using [**Blocking**](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/cats/effect/Blocker.html).

Comment: That wouldn't really work. I assume the caller is also generic in F[_] up to the main method so how does the caller obtain a ContextShift[IO]?

Comment: Usually through [**IOApp**](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/ioapp.html) - give it a look to the documentation.

Comment: I also use IOApp and I checked the docs and code but I couldn't find any way of removing the dependency to IO

Comment: BTW, what exactly do you want to do? Execute some code on a custom **EC** or just introducing async boundaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I took the liberty to rewrite your code, hope it helps:

```
import cats.effect._

object Functions {
  def sampleFunction[F[_]: Sync : ContextShift](file: String, blocker: Blocker): F[String] = {
    val handler: Resource[F, Int] =
      Resource.make(
        blocker.blockOn(openFile(file))
      ) { handler =>
        blocker.blockOn(closeFile(handler))
      }

    handler.use(handler => doWork(handler))
  }

  private def openFile[F[_]: Sync](file: String): F[Int] = Sync[F].delay {
    println(s"Opening file $file with handler 2")
    2
  }

  private def closeFile[F[_]: Sync](handler: Int): F[Unit] = Sync[F].delay {
    println(s"Closing file handler $handler")
  }

  private def doWork[F[_]: Sync](handler: Int): F[String] = Sync[F].delay {
    println(s"Calculating the value on file handler $handler")
    "The final value" 
  }
}

object Main extends IOApp {
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val result = Blocker[IO].use { blocker =>
      Functions.sampleFunction[IO](file = "filePath", blocker)
    }

    for {
      data <- result
      _ <- IO(println(data))
    } yield ExitCode.Success
  }
}
```

*You can see it running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/TyCujpqORyS3sseEZA8q3w/10)*.

So, what does this code does.
First, it creates a **Resource** for the file, since `close` has to be done, even on guarantee or on failure.
It is using **Blocker** to run the `open` and `close` operations on a blocking thread poo *(that is done using **ContextShift**)*.
Finally, on the main, it creates a default **Blocker** for instance, for **IO*, and uses it to call your function; and prints the result.

Fell free to ask any question.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question, I have updated my example code. I want to be able to use targeted ContextShift, not the global one, not one passed all the way down.

Comment: @ColOfAbrRiX so it seems you do not understand how `cats-effect` works. You never create more than one **ContextShift**, you only need one. What you create are multiple **ExecutionContexts**, and here wr have two, the global one used by all the operations and the blocking one used for opening and closing the file.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand `cats-effects` properly, hence this question. I don't see how to use multiple `ExecutionContexts` and only one `ContextShift`. In your answer, how can `sampleFunction` run on an `ExecutionContext` that is **not** created by `Main`? If you haven't already, take a look at my updated Scastie code.

Comment: @ColOfAbRiX So the **ContextShift** has two important operations, `shift` and `evalOn` the first one is used to return to the default **EC** of `F` or for introducing an async boundary so the scheduler can reassign work. The second one is used to evaluate some specific effect on another **EC**. You usually do not want to create multiple **CS**, but if you want / have to for any reason, that is a responsability of the person who has an specific `F`, since its creation depends on the implementation. But, usually you only want one which is passed implicitly and you create custom **EC** if needed

Comment: For example, my snippet uses an additional blocking **EC** under the **Blocker** helper. But, you may replace that with just a simple **EC** and use `evalOn` and `shift` to do what you want. Now, who should create the **EC** is a design decision, usually the responsability is of the caller, but you may provide an overload which provides a default **EC** for simple use cases.

Comment: It starts to make sense now, although I'm thinking how to apply what you say to difference scenarios like fs2.Stream. Doing some tests....

Comment: @ColOfAbRiX I would recommend you to continue this discussion in [**gitter**](https://gitter.im/typelevel/cats-effect) since there you can get a more real time experience as well as there are more skilled people than myself.